# Error in Spring Tool Suite "Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins

Tags: java, maven

After importing my project into my IDE, Spring Tool Suite Version: 4.8.1.RELEASE, there is an error in the pom.xml file, the error message is as follows:
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0:clean (execution:
auto-clean, phase: initialize)

These are the content of my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<parent>
    <groupId>com.pmt.poc</groupId>
    <artifactId>pmt-service-bom</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>resource-service</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<name>resource-service</name>
<description>PMO Tool</description>

<properties>
    <pmt-util.version>0.5.0</pmt-util.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Add other dependencies as you need -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.pmt.poc</groupId>
        <artifactId>pmt-util</artifactId>
        <version>${pmt-util.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I have tried other solutions offered but they don't seem to solve the other problems. Please let me know if you need more information. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is covered on the m2eclipse documentation:

https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/documentation/m2e-execution-not-covered.html

You can either mark it as ignored, by adding the following, or you can select it for execution:

```
<pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
     <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
     <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
     <version>1.0.0</version>
     <configuration>
       <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
         <pluginExecutions>
           <pluginExecution>
             <pluginExecutionFilter>
               <groupId>some-group-id</groupId>
               <artifactId>some-artifact-id</artifactId>
               <versionRange>[1.0.0,)</versionRange>
               <goals>
                 <goal>some-goal</goal>
               </goals>
             </pluginExecutionFilter>
             <action>
               <ignore/>
             </action>
           </pluginExecution>
         </pluginExecutions>
       </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
     </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

Comment: I have read this manual, I think the line "M2Eclipse provides a quick-fix associated with “plugin execution not covered” to easily create"  says that the above lines can be added  using a function in the IDE.  But I can't seem to find it in the Eclipse. How do we get this quick-fix suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: I have managed to overcome this problem by applying the Quick Fix proposed by the Eclipse. It managed to generate the pluginManagement element in my pom.xml. Thanks for pointing this out..